# Apollo Client and invalidateQueries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

In React Query we have `invalidateQueries` to mark cached data as stale. And it helps us to refetch all related queries

Do we have any equivalent function in Apollo Client? I have a fetched list of entities and when I create/update a new entity I would like to mark cached data as stale so they automatically refetch data from server (I don't want to manipulate cache to reflect new changes, I would like to get new data from server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this:

1. Manipulate the apollo cache directly to remove the stale elements
2. *refetch* the query as a side effect of the mutation. [Documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries)

```
// Refetches two queries after mutation completes
const [addTodo, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO, {
  refetchQueries: [
    GET_POST, // DocumentNode object parsed with gql
    'GetComments' // Query name
  ],
});
```